# Why is the default view always redirecting me to the popular tab?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, new-nav, cookies

If I'm not mistaken, my last tab and view was remembered when I was visiting [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com). At the moment no matter what I do if I click on the main logo or just type the address it redirects me to the popular tab.

Here is the GIF image of that behaviour:

[image]

Yes, I tried to clear cookies, tried it in an incognito Window and all the fancy stuff.

Comment: Did you try Internet Explorer 6?

Comment: @hjpotter92 lol.. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been made obsolete by the new release.